# custom view screenshot programmatically not working in android

Tags: android, screenshot, android-custom-view, android-screen

i have custom-view like this,

```
public class RoundedCornerLayout extends FrameLayout
{
    private final static float CORNER_RADIUS = 100.0f;

    private Bitmap maskBitmap;
    private Paint paint, maskPaint;
    private float cornerRadius;

    public RoundedCornerLayout(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public RoundedCornerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RoundedCornerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        p = new Paint();
        p.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        p.setStyle(android.graphics.Paint.Style.STROKE);
        p.setStrokeWidth(6);

        pp = new Paint();
        pp.setColor(Color.parseColor("#686868"));

        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        cornerRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, CORNER_RADIUS, metrics);

        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        maskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
        maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    Paint p;
    Paint pp;

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {

        android.util.Log.e("MAYUR", "draw");

        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, canvas.getWidth() / 2, pp);

        Bitmap offscreenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas offscreenCanvas = new Canvas(offscreenBitmap);

        super.draw(offscreenCanvas);

        if (maskBitmap == null)
        {
            maskBitmap = createMask(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        }

        offscreenCanvas.drawBitmap(maskBitmap, 0f, 0f, maskPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(offscreenBitmap, 0f, 0f, paint);

        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, (canvas.getWidth() - 6) / 2, p);
    }

    private Bitmap createMask(int width, int height)
    {
        Bitmap mask = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mask);

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, width, height), cornerRadius, cornerRadius, paint);

        return mask;
    }
}
```

and i am taking screenshot like this,

```
View v1 = ll_contain;
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
v1.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

and saving bitmap to sdcard, but saving result is different than showing in screen. why? where i am going to wrong?

please give me direction to solve this problem, i tried to search problem but i didn't find this type of such problem to anyone.

show of view in screen is like,

[image]

while taking screenshot, it save like,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem (for a `Drawable`), and the problem was essentially in using `canvas.getHeight()` and `canvas.getWidth()` methods for the position and size while making the `drawCircle` call. While actually drawing the view, these methods return the same values as the view dimensions, and everything went well. While drawing the screenshot, these would return the height and width of the whole screenshot instead of the the dimensions of the view.

The solution is to compute variables `canvasHeight` and `canvasWidth` as 
follows:

- For drawable: `canvasWidth = getBounds().width();`
- For view: `canvasWidth = getRight() - getLeft();`

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and I'm not experiencing any issue/artifact when saving the drawing cache to the sdcard, as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image: device screenshot vs drawing cache]

How are you saving the bitmap to the sdcard? I'm using the following method, invoked when the layout is ready:

```
private void saveScreenShot(){
        View v1 = findViewById(R.id.container);
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        v1.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test.png");
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

You can try to force the *layer type* of the view to *SOFTWARE* in your `init()` method and see if something changes:

```
private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
  setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
  //...
}
```

Comment: thanks for testing my code, when you use RoundedCornerLayout in xml at that time give its height and width 200dp and save it , definitely problem will occur.

Comment: @MayurR.Amipara I've set both width and height to 200dp and still no problem when saving.